# Software for daily backups (Linux)

Tags: gratis, linux, backup

I am looking for a piece of software (preferably with GUI) that will automatically make daily backups of my entire system and allow to revert with relative ease.

Is there something that can do something of this nature?

Comment: what would you like to backup? the usual home-files, also the root or just the your personal files?

Comment: That's indeed a bit broad. Please take a look at [existing linux-backup questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[backup]+[linux]+answers%3A1) which are already answered, and see if any of those fit. Otherwise, please [edit] your question and make clear what's different :) Thanks!

Comment: Did you even bother to Google?

Comment: @Mawg Well yes I did. Thanks to izzy's like I found Back in Time which seems to do the deal.

Comment: Then hopefully @Izzy will propose that as an answer and you will accept it. If he doesn't then after a few days you should post an answer yourself and accept it. That's fine, we just want to leave a trail for others to follow in future, so that they will know what word for you. Btw, no offence, but the question was rather vague. Can you please post the main features of the s/w in either your answer or a comment to Izzy's answer. That will help future searchers to determine if this is the answer for them. Thanks & welcome aboard.

Comment: @Mawg I've just linked to other answers which I thought might fit the needs. So **Slava:** As Mawg pointed out, it's even welcome if you [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question). Please do so, and link to the answers taken from to give them the due credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats to the link provided by @Izzy I found something that fit my needs perfectly from [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/614/13525): BackinTime.

It has all the options I might ever need and even though I didn't try it out yet (as in restore from a backup), it looks like it would work just fine.

Comment: Interesting question, and answer ... Though waiting to actualy TEST your backups until you really ever need them is bad .... really bad ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens All your files get backed up to a specific directory. Nothing could possibly go wrong.

Comment: @Slava Knyazev I assure you that many things still may go wrong. Untested backup is nearly worthless.